# In VBA, how do I read a bookmark that is an array?

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word, bookmarks

Information being pulled into MS word via a bookmark is an array and is being placed in a table. I need to replace some text in that array. How can I do that via VBA.

For example:

Incoming is `bookmark1 = ("question 1","TRUE",question 2,"False",.......)`

And need to change to `bookmark1 = ("question 1","Yes",question 2,"No",.......)`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this as the basis and add salt and pepper to taste...

```
Replace ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(1).Range.Text, "True", "Yes"
Replace ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(1).Range.Text, "False", "No"
```

Based on your comment and your example that is showing the value of Bookmark1 as a string then ...

Bookmark1 = Replace(Bookmark1, "True", "Yes")

Comment: Thanks, but the bookmark is an actual array. I need to iterate through the array and replace any item that says true to yes and false to no. Your code above only works if the bookmark is a string.

Comment: How else can you place an array in a table other than as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks clarity. For starters, it is not apparent what 'bookmark1' has to do with a table - it's not even a bookmark in any sense that Word would recognise as one.

As for changing the array contents:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim bookmark1(), i As Long
bookmark1 = Array("question 1", "TRUE", "question 2", "False")
For i = 0 To UBound(bookmark1)
  bookmark1(i) = Replace(bookmark1(i), "True", "Yes", , , vbTextCompare)
  bookmark1(i) = Replace(bookmark1(i), "False", "No", , , vbTextCompare)
Next
MsgBox Join(bookmark1, ", ")
End Sub
```